# load own map based on location on iphone4

Tags: iphone

i want to load my own map based on current location , lets say i have all the images based on zoom level
like zoom=16 (then all images of 16) , zoom=14(all images of 14 levl)

But how to load these  maps based on location , i mean how to get notified so that i can load images???

Comment: You want your app to be notified when the user zooms?

Comment: yes and load the appropriates images based on zoom in or out?? actually mu concern is how to show the images based on zoom level and that too exact image (like lets say current location)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might be exactly what you need: [**Route Me**](https://github.com/route-me/route-me), an iOS map library for performing the standard UIMapView types of things with your own maps.

Comment: but i want to load my own map not openstreet ,,lets say  i have current lat/long and then i will call my images from resource folder ,but how to call image folder based on lat/long

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought it allowed you to use your own map source, not the three specific alternates they support.